# Do I need to lemmatize my corpus when performing collocation analysis on inflective languages?

Tags: corpora, morphosyntax, collocations, corpus-linguistics

Do I need to lemmatize my corpus when I am going to perform a collocational analysis? Several language, including English, are to a certain extent inflective. These inflections sometimes carries morphosyntactical information, and thus removing the inflections may also remove important morphosyntactical information of a sentence. I wonder if it is a standard practice to lemmatize corpus when doing collocational analysis. My ultimate goal is to analyze the collocation on the Russian news corpora on several nouns related to abstract political construct, e.g. "the church".

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that anybody can answer if we do not know what exactly you are doing during your analysis. Some other notes: 1. Even within the same single language, different dictionaries or other books may choose to use different form as lemma (e.g. for Latin verbs: first-person-singular-present form or infinitive). 2. Some books use an abstract form (e.g. stem) as lemma, which is not actual word (e.g. in Japanese, lemma *kak-* for verb whose terminal form is *kaku*). 3. Different lexemes may happen to share some forms (e.g. in English: [ *lie*, ***lay***, *lain* ], [ ***lay***, *laid*, *laid* ]).

Comment: @Arfrever added my goal of analysis. Also thanks for the additional notes!

Answer (score 1):

When you lemmatise a corpus, you usually don't throw away the original wordforms, you just add another layer of annotation to it. There are different ways to do it, one popular format is the vertical format (vrt) of the [Open Corpus Workbench](https://cwb.sourceforge.io/) that puts each token in a line and adds additional layers of annotation in tab separated columns. It is similar to the [CONLLU format](https://universaldependencies.org/docs/format.html) in this respect, but CONLLU gives fixed meanings to the columns and forces you to have placeholder values in unused columns while the vrt format is fully flexible but forces you to document the meanings of the columns.

Doing lemmatisation and part-of-speech annotation is part of the basic annotation that we expect in an annotated corpus, and it is always a good idea. If your analysis comes out better on the lemmata or wordforms is hard to predict, try both and look what comes out better.

Answer (score 1):

It was not standard practice when I was still in academia (1994-2013) working on collocation analysis (albeit mostly on English corpora).

Lemmatisation can mask the fact that only specific word forms collocate with each other; this is problematic if you are actually looking at phraseology/(semi-)fixed phrases etc. — so if this is what you are interested, don't use lemmatisation.

However, in more heavily inflected languages than English, it might be useful to group word forms together; but even here, a full lemmatisation might be too much, so ideally you would do your analysis without lemmatisation first, and then look at the list of collocates you get. If in there you find a lof of inflected variants, then lemmatisation might be useful to give you a better picture of it. But you might find that only two or three forms out of a much larger paradigm actually collocate, in which case lemmatisation might give you a false impression.

You can compare lemmatisation with the process of smoothing in analysing time series: in doing so you eliminate the details, but might be able to more easily discern a general trend. But you would always first look at the raw data before deciding on smoothing.